# How can I interpret Ergometry results?

Tags: cardio, heart, medicine

The information that I found was limited to interpreting the maximum METs reading, however ergometry results contain also HR in every stage and much more. What can I learn from this fitnesswize?

So say a person is taking two ergometry tests in the later one his HR in the 3 early stages are lower but higher in the final ones. Could I deduce that he has improved his medium aerobic fitness but lost some of his intensive aerobic-anaerobic fitness?